# How to change the plot style of several curves, in this manipulate box?

Tags: plotting, manipulate, color, style, output

I'm sure this is very easy, but I'm currently unable to make it to work properly.  I just need to give different colors and style to the three curves shown in this manipulate box:

```
fun[gamma_] := Plot[x^2 - gamma x^3,{x, 0, 1},PlotRange -> All]

Manipulate[
    Show[
    {fun[gamma], fun[0],  fun[2]},
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}},
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]}, {Medium, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.40], Dashed}},
    PlotRangePadding -> None],
    {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}
]
```

Currently, the three curves are having the same color and style.  I need the two fixed curves to get a medium thickness, dashed gray color, while the moving curve stays in blue.  What's wrong with this simple code?  Of course, I could introduce a style parameter into the `fun` function:

`fun[gamma_, style_] := Plot[x^2 - gamma x^3, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> style]`

but is there a simpler way to achieve the same effect?

Comment: `Clear[fun];
fun[gamma_] := x^2 - gamma x^3;
Manipulate[
 Plot[{fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]}, {Medium, 
     RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.40], Dashed}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None], {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]`

Comment: Hmm, I need to have separate `Plot`for my full code to work...

Comment: @cvgmt, you mean like the modification I made to the `fun`function (last part in my question)?

Comment: Plot several curves and set different `PlotStyle` we only need one `Plot`.

Answer (score 1):

```
directives = {Directive[Thick, RGBColor[0.40, 0.40, 0.80]], 
   Directive[Thickness@Medium, Gray, Dashed], 
   Directive[Thickness@Medium, Gray, Dashed]};
```

If you do not want to make any changes to `fun`:

#### 1. Epilog + Show

Extract the line primitives from `fun[0]` and `fun[2]` and used them `Epilog` with desired styles:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[fun[gamma], 
  Epilog -> 
    Thread[{Rest@directives, Cases[#, _Line, All] & /@ {fun[0], fun[2]}}],
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None],
 {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

#### 2. Post-processing

```
ClearAll[replaceStyles]
replaceStyles[dirs_] := Module[{d = dirs}, 
  ReplaceAll[{_Directive, l_Line} :> {Last[d = RotateLeft[d]], l}]]
```

You can use `replaceStyles` in two ways:

**i.** Wrap `Show` with `replaceStyles[directives]`:

```
Manipulate[replaceStyles[directives]@
  Show[{fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
 {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

**ii.** Wrap `{fun[...],..}` in first argument of `Show` with `replaceStyles[directives]`:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[replaceStyles[directives] @ {fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2]}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None], 
 {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

**iii.** Use it as option setting for `DisplayFunction` in `Show[...]`:

```
Manipulate[Show[{fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2]}, 
  DisplayFunction -> replaceStyles[directives], 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None],
 {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

#### 3. An alternative post-processing

```
ClearAll[injectDirectives]
injectDirectives[d_] := MapThread[ReplaceAll[l_Line :> {#, l}]@#2 &]@{d, #} &

Manipulate[Show[
  injectDirectives[directives]@{fun[gamma], fun[0], fun[2]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> None],
 {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

#### 4. A more flexible `fun`

Alternatively, you can modify `fun` to take options:

```
ClearAll[morefun]

morefun[gamma_, o : OptionsPattern[]] := Plot[x^2 - gamma x^3, {x, 0, 1},
 o, PlotStyle -> Directive[Thickness@Medium, Gray, Dashed]]

Manipulate[Show[
  {morefun[gamma, PlotStyle -> Automatic], morefun[0], morefun[2]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}},
  PlotRangePadding -> None],
 {{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]

If you like you can add additional options:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{morefun[gamma, PlotStyle -> Automatic, Mesh -> 5, 
    MeshStyle -> PointSize @ Large], 
   morefun[0], 
   morefun[2, PlotStyle -> {Dashing[Medium], AbsoluteThickness[3]}, 
      ColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None], 
{{gamma, 0.5, "gamma"}, 0, 2, 0.01}]
```

[image]